# BeautifulSoup doesn't extract the table

Tags: python

[image]

```
import urllib.request as urllib2 #To query website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #To parse website
import pandas as pd


#specify the url and open 

url3 = 'http://www.thatscricket.com/ipl/2014/results/index.html'
req = urllib2.urlopen(url3)




soup = BeautifulSoup(req,"html5lib")
all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
print(all_tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the content of your requested data

```
content = req.readall()
```

as you examine the content:

```
print(content)
```

and surprisingly there is not table!!!

But if you check the page source you can see tables in it.

As I examined there should be some problem with urllib.request and there is some escape sequence on the page which causes that urllib get only part of that page.
So I could be able to fix the problem by using requests instead of urllib

first

```
pip install requests
```

Then change your code to this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url3 = 'http://www.thatscricket.com/ipl/2014/results/index.html'
req = requests.get(url3)


soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,"html5lib")
all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
print(all_tables)
```